# How to insert a custom search fields in a views page

Tags: database, views

I have a view page showing some books and I want to have an advanced search with search criterias at the top of this page. The search box should search inside the books page or books content type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your view, all you simply need to do is add a filter criteria and expose it to the user. So you add a filter criteria of your content type, that you will not need to expose since thats the one you want to search on.

If you are searching on the title, you add a filter criteria, select content:title, it takes you to the next selection, select expose to visitors. You can also choose what operator to use and if need be, you can also expose the operator. See screenshot

[image]

Comment: thank you. but i am a bit confused. i want to have some two or three text field which users can input the title of the book, the author and the publisher etc then submit their search.

Comment: Then add more field to the filter criteria, and expose them all. The title was just an example. You can add as much fields as you want